# TYPE R basic separate function

Tags: r

I am new at learning coding. Can someone tell me why my code is not working. I am using a simple chart named employee. It has 3 columns, id, name, job title. I am trying to separate the name into two columns, here is the code I'm trying to use.

```
new_employee_chart = employee %>%  
  separate(employee, name, into = c("first_name", "last_name"), sep = " ")
```

and this is the error message I get

```
Error:
! Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
✖ Subscript `!!enquo(col)` has the wrong type `data.frame<
  id       : integer
  name     : character
  job_title: character
>`.
ℹ It must be numeric or character.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

this is the data

```
> print(employee)
   id              name    job_title
1   1       John Mendes Professional
2   2       Rob Stewart   Programmer
3   3 Rachel Abrahamson   Management
4   4   Christy Hickman     Clerical
5   5    Johnson Harper    Developer
6   6    Candace Miller   Programmer
7   7     Carlson Landy   Management
8   8      Pansy Jordan     Clerical
9   9      Darius Berry    Developer
10 10    Claudia Garcia   Programmer
```

I just want to understand why it did not work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Remove `employee` in `separate()` because you are already piping that in.

Comment: @Phil thank you for your answer, appreciate it.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue & it was because my data was not separated by a space, but by a \n, which I didn't know by looking at it. If you scraped this data from some other source or didn't make it yourself, the issue may be that the separating feature is not a space but some other character.

Proof:
final = final %>% separate(Price, c("Gold", "Diamonds"), sep = " ") results in...
!!enquo(col)` must be numeric or character, not a <data.frame> object.

final = final %>% separate(Price, c("Gold", "Diamonds"), sep = "\n") produces no errors & splits it correctly. Here is a snip of my data to demonstrate how it looks like the separating factor was a space:
[snip of data demonstrating space appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw93O.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).